# while(getline(fin, str)){} still processing data even after reaching eof

Tags: c++, file-io, getline

I'm trying to process data I'm reading from a file using getline() as a while condition. However, even when getline reads to the end of my file, it still keeps processing data and I can't figure out why.

I tried putting fin.ignore at the end of my while loop, and that did solve one problem but created another. Let me show you what I mean.

Here's my code:

```
   int i{ 0 };
   string name_buffer;
   string quantity_buffer;
   string price_buffer;
   ifstream fin("in_inventory.txt");
   if (fin) {
      while (getline(fin, name_buffer, ';') && i < g_kMaxArray) {
         getline(fin, quantity_buffer, ';');
         getline(fin, price_buffer, '\n');
         p_item_list_[i] =  new Product(stoi(quantity_buffer) == 0, name_buffer, stoi(quantity_buffer), stod(price_buffer));
         i++;
         item_count_++;
      }
   }
   else {
      cout << "Error: Failed to open input file." << endl;
   }
   fin.close();
```

I read this text file:

```
AMD Ryzen 1600X 6-Core CPU;9;99.99
WD Blue 1TB HDD;24;49.99
MSI GTX 1080 Duke Graphics Card;6;519.99
NZXT H442 ATX Case;21;89.99
MSI B350 ATX Motherboard;19;149.99
WD Blue 256GB SSD;28;69.99
Cooler Master Hyper 212 Evo CPU Heatsink;41;15.99
Corsair Vengance 8Gb (2x4GB) Dual Channel Memory;18;39.99
Corsair CX650M 650 Watt Powersupply;16;59.99
Schiit Fulla 2;25;89.99
Logitech G410 Tenkeyless Mechanical Keyboard;7;79.99
Corsair H100iv2 All-in-one CPU Water Cooler;14;109.99
Steel Series Qck+ Mousepad;54;18.99
TP-Link Archer T6E PCIe WiFi Card;42;39.99
Logitech G502 Mouse;61;47.00
Beyerdynamic DT 770 Studio Headphones;36;178.99
```

As far as I can tell there are no missing or extra semicolons and there's no newline characters at the end of the file.

Here's my output without fin.ignore():

```
____________________________________________________________________________________
|Item ID|Restocking?|Name                                            |Quantity|Price |
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   5708|   false   |AMD Ryzen 1600X 6-Core CPU                      |9       |99.99 |
|   2760|   false   |WD Blue 1TB HDD                                 |24      |49.99 |
|   7220|   false   |MSI GTX 1080 Duke Graphics Card                 |6       |519.99|
|   4110|   false   |NZXT H442 ATX Case                              |21      |89.99 |
|   9026|   false   |MSI B350 ATX Motherboard                        |19      |149.99|
|   9636|   false   |WD Blue 256GB SSD                               |28      |69.99 |
|   5559|   false   |Cooler Master Hyper 212 Evo CPU Heatsink        |41      |15.99 |
|   5541|   false   |Corsair Vengance 8Gb (2x4GB) Dual Channel Memory|18      |39.99 |
|   7406|   false   |Corsair CX650M 650 Watt Powersupply             |16      |59.99 |
|   2568|   false   |Schiit Fulla 2                                  |25      |89.99 |
|   4904|   false   |Logitech G410 Tenkeyless Mechanical Keyboard    |7       |79.99 |
|   7280|   false   |Corsair H100iv2 All-in-one CPU Water Cooler     |14      |109.99|
|   4299|   false   |Steel Series Qck+ Mousepad                      |54      |18.99 |
|   8583|   false   |TP-Link Archer T6E PCIe WiFi Card               |42      |39.99 |
|   1103|   false   |Logitech G502 Mouse                             |61      |47.00 |
|   4709|   false   |Beyerdynamic DT 770 Studio Headphones           |36      |178.99|
|   2900|   false   | //This line shouldn't exist
                                               |36      |178.99| //This line shouldn't exist
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And here's my output with fin.ignore, it gets rid of the extra output, but deletes the first character of the name of the product for every product after the first:

```
 ____________________________________________________________________________________
|Item ID|Restocking?|Name                                            |Quantity|Price |
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   6293|   false   |AMD Ryzen 1600X 6-Core CPU                      |9       |99.99 |
|   3407|   false   |D Blue 1TB HDD                                  |24      |49.99 |
|   3638|   false   |SI GTX 1080 Duke Graphics Card                  |6       |519.99|
|   2358|   false   |ZXT H442 ATX Case                               |21      |89.99 |
|   3370|   false   |SI B350 ATX Motherboard                         |19      |149.99|
|   1620|   false   |D Blue 256GB SSD                                |28      |69.99 |
|   5632|   false   |ooler Master Hyper 212 Evo CPU Heatsink         |41      |15.99 |
|   5847|   false   |orsair Vengance 8Gb (2x4GB) Dual Channel Memory |18      |39.99 |
|   3866|   false   |orsair CX650M 650 Watt Powersupply              |16      |59.99 |
|   6181|   false   |chiit Fulla 2                                   |25      |89.99 |
|   1202|   false   |ogitech G410 Tenkeyless Mechanical Keyboard     |7       |79.99 |
|   5170|   false   |orsair H100iv2 All-in-one CPU Water Cooler      |14      |109.99|
|   2230|   false   |teel Series Qck+ Mousepad                       |54      |18.99 |
|   8477|   false   |P-Link Archer T6E PCIe WiFi Card                |42      |39.99 |
|   5789|   false   |ogitech G502 Mouse                              |61      |47.00 |
|   5263|   false   |eyerdynamic DT 770 Studio Headphones            |36      |178.99|
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Whats the best solution here? What exactly is going here that's causing this output? Thanks.

Comment: Crazy thought, what happens if you just add 1 extra newline to your file? Specifically, does it work as intended?

Comment: @Chipster Nah, just tried it with and without fin.ignore() same exact output, no difference

Comment: There's no need to call `fin.close();`. The destructor will do that.

Answer (score 2):

In the outer while-loop, read one line at a time to `str`, then in the inner while loop extract each field, from the just extracted line, like this:

```
if (fin.is_open()) {
    string str, buffer;     
    while (getline(fin, str) && item_count_< g_kMaxArray) {
        stringstream line{ str };
        int field_count = 0;
        cout << endl << "New Line - " << str << endl;
        string field0, field1, field2;
        while (getline(line, buffer, ';')) { 
            field_count == 0 ? field0 = buffer : field_count == 1 ? field1 = buffer : field2 = buffer;
            field_count++;
        }
        p_item_list_[item_count_] = new Product(stoi(field1) == 0, field0, stoi(field1), stod(field2));
        item_count_++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` condition is wrong.

```
while (i < g_kMaxArray && // MUST be first
     getline(fin, name_buffer, ';') &&
     getline(fin, quantity_buffer, ';') &&
     getline(fin, price_buffer, '\n')) { 
   ...
 }
```

Reading the input line by line and parsing each line is arguably better in your case. This is just a generic way to read several inputs in the same loop iteration.